# Load JSON file in my Lambda project Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to access a json file that is in my lambda structure as following:

[image]

the problem is that I can access and load config_in_root.json but I can't access confi.json in src/ cause of the error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I know I can keep in root, but I want to know why this is happening.
Here is my code to test both files:

**lambda_function:**

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
from app.src import soma

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    filename = Path('config_in_root.json').resolve()
    print(filename)
    
    with open(filename) as f:
        config = json.load(f)
        print("done in root")
   
   
    result = soma.get_result()
    print(result)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello World from Lambda!')
    }
```

**soma:**

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

def get_result():

    try:
        filename = Path('config.json').resolve()
        print(filename)

        with open(filename) as f:
            config = json.load(f)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print("except in get_result: ", e)


Function Logs
START RequestId: 82dc4755-c6f7-46e5-9ec3-2405ab398b92 Version: $LATEST
/var/task/config_in_root.json
done in root
/var/task/config.json
except in get_result:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/config.json'
```

I tried to modify the path with `"./" , "../" , "src/" , "app/src/"` and didn't work.

Comment: It looks like it would need to be `../../` (two folders up) if the JSON file is in your `HelloWorld` folder. Are you certain it is even getting included in your deployment zip file? You can always open the zip file to browse it if you are not sure.

Comment: You can print the results of `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir(...)` to help you debug this.

Comment: Rather than worrying about cwd, you can be explicit in the path based off the filenames of the modules:  `os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], "config_in_root.json")` to get the path to the root file, and `os.path.join(os.path.split(soma.__file__)[0], "config.json")` to get the path to the module's filename.